# Member count of closed Facebook groups?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-group

Is it possible to get the member count of closed Facebook groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible you can only retrieve 500 max currently via Graph API (https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/members)

> All of the users who are members of this group (can only currently return the first 500 members)

Via FQL you can retrieve up to 5000 I believe

```
select gid, uid from group_member where gid = GROUP_ID
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group_member/